# what the equation ${x^2-y^2}\le{a}$ represents?

Tags: analysis

I know that $x^2-y^2=a$ represents hyperbola but I am not able to imagine ${x^2-y^2}\le{a}$ represents?

Comment: It represents all points on and between two branches of that hyperbola

Comment: Try adjusting $a$ in this visualizer https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hgbs67h4k0 Notice how the case $a=0$ is degenerate and the change of sign disconnect the colored area

Answer (score 0):

For all $(x,y)$, either $x^2 - y^2 < a, x^2 - y^2 = a$ or $x^2 - y^2 > 0$.

Pick the point $(0, 0)$, and $0^2 - 0^2 < a$. With a quick sketch, this is the region between the two branches of the hyperbola, including the hyperbola itself ($≤$).

Comment: Furthermore in the special case $a=0$ we have a nice interpretation of the region $x^2-y^2 <0$: it corresponds to the interior of the light cone in the standard $2$-dimensional Minkovski spacetime of special relativity (with coordinates $(x,t)$ and metric given by $ds^2 = dx^2 - dt^2$), *i.e.* all the accessible points in spacetime with speed bounded by that of the light.

If you have a physical mind maybe this can help get a better picture!